# ScatterPlotDemo-JfreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

Can any one please provide me the Source Code for "ScatterPlotDemo1" which comes with "JfreeChart DevloperGuide".I am developing exactly the same Application so it would be very helpful for me if I can get the code  for the following Image attached.

Thanks very Much

> http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/ScatterPlotDemo1.png

Answer (score 1):

Any one of these recent [scatter plot demos](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:230513%20scatter) would probably be a better starting point. The only difference is the demonstration dataset. [`ScatterPlotDemo1`](http://code.google.com/p/uidesign/source/browse/trunk/UIDProject/src/testers/ScatterPlotDemo1.java?spec=svn19&r=19) is not hard to find, but the required [`SampleXYDataset2`](http://www.koders.com/java/fidDDF4FDB83BDB6F78A3237CFC4452E3278C2C342C.aspx) is less than exemplary. I'd look at `nextGaussian()` to  vary the slope of a [line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29).

As you use the library [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:840865%20%5Bjfreechart%5D), I'd recommend [*The JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/uidesign/source/browse/trunk/UIDProject/src/testers/ScatterPlotDemo1.java?spec=svn19&r=19